# DO I need to install Oracle provider for .NET 4 in the server

Tags: .net, asp.net, oracle, provider

I've been handed over a web applicaion to which I need to make some changes. One of the first ones is to change Microsoft's System.Data.OracleClient to Oracle's Oracle provider for .NET as when I compile I get warning that I should use third party library to connect to Oracle database. On my own computer I've already installed Oracle Provider for .NET. The application is layered and  I do all these connection, querying and updating and stuff in a Data Access Layer (DAL). Then I get the dll and put it in Bin folder of the website. Now, if I comile the DAL with new library and replace the dll in website with the newly created one will it still work or do I have to install Oracle Provider for .Net in the server too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use a "xcopy deployment" of the ODP.NET, see this link: [Deploy Oracle Data Provider.NET](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e18754/InstallODP.htm)